# how to config highlight style in spacemacs as sublimetext did?

Tags: spacemacs, faces, highlighting

I used highlight-symbol to show all selected text in spacemacs, but that looks not very good as sublime text did as following pic:

My question is that if  spacemacs could use box style without color for other selected one? I knows most highlight el could use color to highlight all selected text, that is not good enough.

[image]

Comment: If you are stuck after defining @dalanicolai's `hi-box`, perhaps this way: `(custom-set-faces '(isearch ((t (:inherit hi-box)))) '(lazy-highlight ((t (:inherit hi-box)))))`

Answer (score 1):

You could define a simple face for this as follows:

```lisp
(defface hi-box
  '((t (:box t )))
  "Box face for hi-lock mode."
  :group 'hi-lock-faces)
```

Then don't forget to add it as first element in `hi-lock-face-defaults`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'hi-lock-face-defaults "hi-box")
```

Note that you need to require `hi-lock.el` first for the variable to become available.

Subsequently, to further customize the face you can do `M-x customize-face` `hi-box`. There you can style the box to your liking.

Comment: when I added (add-to-list 'hi-lock-face-defaults "hi-box"), spacemacs shows error as following:   (Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol’s value as variable is void: hi-lock-faces

Comment: Yeah,  as I wrote in the answer, you have to place a `(require 'hi-lock)` before it (before the line with the 'add-to-list').